# AJAX Call - Flickering more for each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a chart (in Yii2 Framework) that can show different report for each period, i need to update the chart if the user click on the button group with 7D-1M-1Y.

The update work, but every time i change the view period with button click, the flicker times before the right chart is shown, becomes higher.

**This is my JS**:

```
if(!$('#7D').hasClass('active') && !$('#1M').hasClass('active') && !$('#1Y').hasClass('active')) { $('#1M').addClass('active'); }
$('#7D').click(function() {
    var myValue = "7D";
    $.get("",{val:myValue},function(data){
        $('.btn').removeClass('active');
        $('#7D').addClass('active');
        $('#w2').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#w2').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
$('#1M').click(function() {
    var myValue = "1M";
    $.get("",{val:myValue},function(data){
        $('.btn').removeClass('active');
        $('#1M').addClass('active');
        $('#w2').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#w2').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
$('#1Y').click(function() {
    var myValue = "1Y";
    $.get("",{val:myValue},function(data){
        $('.btn').removeClass('active');
        $('#1Y').addClass('active');
        $('#w2').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#w2').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

**This is my Button Group**:

```
<?= ButtonGroup::widget([
    'buttons' => [
        ['label' => '7D', 'id' => '7D'],
        ['label' => '1M', 'id' => '1M'],
        ['label' => '1Y', 'id' => '1Y'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

**TIP:** I tried with body instead of #w2 (the id of the chart), and it works properly without increments the flickering time, but flicker one time vertically, when the chart diseppear the page go to the top and then return to the new bottom.

Solve this can also be helpful, i only need a solution, is not important how

Comment: You're probably loading the same javascript code for button clicks in your ajax call. At least, that's the first thing that comes to my mind on how you described your problem. Or there is some other js code in your ajax call that's making the chart and that gets doubled. Check https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view#registerJs()-detail so you can assign a unique key for js code so it won't be doubled when Yii returns the code with ajax (I hope at least).

Comment: @Imaginaroom The js i put in the question, is the whole code i have.

Comment: Are you using some chart widget that you return as a whole in your ajax response?

Comment: @Imaginaroom yes i am using chartjs widget

Comment: So, the way how it works is that the widget adds the js code to the ajax response every single time and that just increases the number of same js code blocks that make the chart. One of the possible solutions for this problem (although not the best one) is to assign a dynamic id to your widget (for example id => 'something' . time()) as that will ensure that previously added js codes won't mess with the new widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your question, I think your click event has been attached to your element for multiple times. To avoid attaching them several times you can use

```
$("#SomeId").off("click").on("click", function({
    // Your logic here.
}));
```

Though the problem on question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks it works! 1 week to solve this problem, thank you very much.